# Can't access UEFI after switching from BIOS on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, bios, efi

I'm currently using an unmodified ASUS K52J laptop running Windows 8 and trying to develop for Windows Phone 8. In order to meet the specifications necessary to successfully run the phone emulator with Visual Studio 2012 (I'm using Express for Windows Phone 8), I'm trying to get to the BIOS settings. My only issue is that I switched to using UEFI boot and haven't been able to figure out how to access it since. I've scoured the web for a host of different keystrokes to enter at boot, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Choose "UEFI Firmware Settings" from the Windows 8 boot options menu (accessed after boot).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/05/22/designing-for-pcs-that-boot-faster-than-ever-before.aspx

As mentioned, the simplest set of instructions for getting there is:

- Run `shutdown /r /o`